# Regular pentagon with its inscribed and circumscribed circles : lines dividing the pentagon and one of the disks into two equal areas

Tags: geometry

Consider a circle inscribed into a regular pentagon.

(a) How to prove amount of straight lines which can dividing into two parts with equal area the disk and the regular pentagon as much as amount of vertex pentagon. Also

(b) amount of straight lines will be same if regular polygon inscribed into a circle.

[image]

Comment: When you say "divide the circle and the pentagon", do you mean "halve" (i.e. divide into equal halves)? Also, "amount of straight line" - do you mean the "number of straight lines"?

Comment: yes. thank you. i'll edit it

Comment: Very very unclear. Do you mean "a diameter of the circumscribed (or inscribed) circle dividing the **area** of the pentagon into two equal **areas**"

Comment: @JeanMarie yes. to prove asosiative properties can apply in case pentagon inscribe circle and vice versa.

Comment: 1)As you have said "yes", there is an evident solution : the diameter passing through one of the vertices, for example passing through $D'$. 2) I don't understand what you mean by **associative** properties.

Comment: amount of straight line which can bisect halves area circle inscribe in regular pentagon = amount of straight line which can bisect halves area pentagon inscribe in circle

Comment: Are these lines diameters of the circle or not ?

Comment: should be diameter to ensure the circle also bisect halves. Same condition if we change a circle to a square.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147237/discussion-between-dea-and-jean-marie).

Comment: The answer by user is the good one.

Answer (score 1):

Hint

The straight line has to be a diameter of the circle (think why).
As already stated in the comments any diameter passing through a vertex is a solution. Let coin them good diameters.
Assume that there is another diameter solving the problem. Let the angle between this diameter and the nearest (say in clockwise direction) good diameter be $x$ ($0<x<\frac\pi5$). The diameter solves the problem if and only if
$$
\tan x+\tan(\frac\pi5-x)=\tan\frac\pi5,
$$
but this is impossible because:
$$
f(x)=\tan x+\tan(\frac\pi5-x)-\tan\frac\pi5<0\quad\text{for}\quad 0<x<\frac\pi5,
$$
since $f(x)$ in this domain is strictly convex and $f(0)=f(\frac\pi5)=0$ (these boundary values correspond to a good diameter).